# How do Google create the distortion effect on the Google Ideas homepage?

Tags: javascript, animation, distortion

The [Google Ideas homepage](https://www.google.com/ideas/) features an animation that distorts the appearance of some of the text and a button with a static sound effect, in order to simulate signal interference as the content transitions from one item to the next.

Here's a Gif in case they change the design:

[image: Google Ideas text distortion gif]

How are they achieving this? I can see classes and styles jumping around in the dev tools, so JavaScript is definitely involved, but I can't find the relevant section of script itself.

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/0ojbJMr06ro

Comment: I guess they are using a canvas with webgl rendering. Search for "canvas" in the javascript. I am not very sure what exactly is going on, since the code is slightly obfuscated (or well, minified) but have a look at canvas and webgl APIs for ideas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not that hard, especially with [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) and [canvas-glitch](https://github.com/snorpey/glitch-canvas).

Basically you just need to convert the DOM element to canvas, and then manipulate the image data to achieve the glitch effect. And with these two libs, that task becomes quite trivial.

```
html2canvas(node, {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        // hide the original node
        node.style.display = "none";
        // add the canvas node to the node's parent
        // practically replacing the original node
        node.parentNode.appendChild(canvas);
        // get the canvas' image data
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        // glitch it
        var parameters = { amount: 1, seed: Math.round(Math.random()*100), iterations: 5, quality: 30 };
        glitch(imageData, parameters, function(imageData) {
            // update the canvas' image data
            ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
        });
    }
});
```

Click here for a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ArtBIT/x12gvs1v/